# Show java servlet process in web

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I'm developing a small web app that queries a few databases to do data predictions, then returns an object with the predicted result.

That's somewhat working already, but data processing in the servlet can go over half an hour depending on query filters, I usually set up a javascript "loading" div on submit, but its a bit sad.

So the question is, can I somehow send messages to the web client while the servlet is processing so it doesn't look like the page died? (improving the loading div with actual info on how the process is going)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the preloader before sending the request and remove that preloader on success.

```
var isBool = false;
function communicateWithServer(){
    $("#preloader").show();
    var isBool = false;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'url',
        data : {

        },
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'text',
        success : function(response) {
             isBool=true;
             $("#preloader").hide();
             //Show success
        },
        error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             $("#preloader").hide();
             //show error
        }
    });
   secondComm();
}
function secondComm(){

    $.ajax({
            url : 'url2',//send the response from your second servlet to this
            data : {

            },
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(response) {

                 $("#preloader").text(response.value);
                 if(!isBool){secondComm();}
                 //
            },
            error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 if(!isBool){secondComm();}
                 //show error
            }
        });

}
```

Please do not get confused with the `jquery` you can do this without `jquery` too.

```
function communicateWithServer() {
  document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = 'block';
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //show success
    } else {
      //show error
    }
    document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = 'none';
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Problem is, for example, how can I send a message to that ajax post every few seconds with info on how the proccessing is going?

Comment: Do you mean some kind of percent value you want to send?

Comment: For example, "X clients proccessed out of 1.000.000", and that updates every few secs

Comment: I think why don't you create another servlet and after init of first communication start communicating with the second and receive the data with that. I am updating the example.

Comment: Updated please have a look

Comment: So I can setup a few global variables that I edit in the first servlet with messages, then use the second one to show?

Comment: Yes, public static var update it in the first and send with the second. And Please upvote and accept if satisfies. You can send json or string from the servlet

Comment: Im testing it, thank you very much for your time, its upvoted but my rep is too low to show it

Comment: Pleasure is mine.